Supabase not redirecting after login (Nuxt)
I'm having an issue where after a successful login using supabase nothing happens on the login page even though the user gets signed in.
Here is my nuxt.config.ts
// https://nuxt.com/docs/api/configuration/nuxt-config
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  extends: [process.env.NUXT_UI_PRO_PATH || "@nuxt/ui-pro"],
  modules: [
    "@nuxt/ui",
    "@nuxt/fonts",
    "@vueuse/nuxt",
    "@nuxt/image",
    "@nuxtjs/eslint-module",
    "@nuxtjs/supabase",
  ],

  plugins: [{ src: "plugins/crisp.js", mode: "client" }],
  ui: {
    icons: ["heroicons", "simple-icons"],
    safelistColors: ["primary", "red", "orange", "green"],
  },
  devtools: {
    enabled: false,
  },
  supabase: {
    redirectOptions: {
      login: "/auth",
      callback: "/",
    },
  },
});


Here is my auth page:
<template>
  <UCard class="max-w-sm w-full bg-white/75 dark:bg-white/5 backdrop-blur">
    <Auth
      :supabaseClient="supabaseClient"
      :appearance="{
        theme: ThemeSupa,
        style: {
          anchor: { color: '#818cf8' },
        },
        variables: {
          dark: {
            colors: {
              brand: '#818cf8',
              brandAccent: '#6a74d7',
              brandButtonText: 'white',
              defaultButtonBackground: '#0f172a',
              defaultButtonBackgroundHover: '#191e36',
              defaultButtonBorder: '#334155',
              defaultButtonText: 'white',
              dividerBackground: '#334155',
              inputBackground: '#0f172a',
              inputBorder: '#334155',
              inputBorderHover: '#223046',
              inputBorderFocus: '#223046',
              inputText: 'white',
              inputLabelText: 'white',
              inputPlaceholder: '#8896ab',
              messageText: 'gray',
              messageTextDanger: 'red',
              anchorTextColor: 'gray',
              anchorTextHoverColor: 'darkgray',
            },
          },
        },
      }"
      :providers="['google', 'twitter', 'discord']"
      theme="dark"
      show-links
      redirect-to="/"
    />
  </UCard>
</template>

<script setup>
// Import predefined theme
import { ThemeSupa } from "@supabase/auth-ui-shared";
import { Auth } from "@nuxtbase/auth-ui-vue";

const supabaseClient = useSupabaseClient();

definePageMeta({
  layout: "auth",
});
</script>


I'm using https://github.com/nuxtbase/auth-ui-vue for the login form.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.
I need the user to be redirected to the index.vue page after successful login.
